# How to fetch current state of a Wave?

Tags: google-wave

With the current Wave API, is there any way to fetch the current state of a Wave? I want to write a little notifier app that observes any changes in a certain wave and notifies me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wave server will send you an update whenever a wave changes, so this is the default. What it can't do is send you the "current" value because of the delta logic on which Wave is based. So you will get a stream of deltas until the Wave server can assume that your copy of the value is current.